# Show View when scroll up Scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-hooks, react-typescript

How to limit the quantity of View inside of a scrollview.

My component take too much time to render, because the map function renders too many views. I need to show only 10 views, and when scroll up, renders more 10.

I'm using react native, hooks and typescript.

Comment: Please provide the code on how you are doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you have a large number of list data don't use scrollview. Because initially, it loads all the data to scrollview component & it costs performance as well.

Use [flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) in react-native instead of scrollview & you can limit the number of items to render in the initially using [initialNumToRender](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender). When you reach the end of the scroll position you can call [onEndReached](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onendreached) method to load more data.

A sample will like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";

class FlatListDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: 1,
        seed: this.state.seed + 1,
        refreshing: true
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round />;
  };

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar
              title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
              subtitle={item.email}
              avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.email}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={50}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default FlatListDemo;
```

[Check this](https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to Flatlist! But initialNumToRender is not working as expected.

The flatlist is rendering all 150 transactions, not only 15, and i have no idea what to do.

I'm running .map() from another array with all others transactions to create newMonths with only those transactions that i want to use `data={newMonths}`.

```
  let newMonths = [];
  const createArrayMonth = histInfos.map(function (info) {
    if (info.created_at.slice(5, 7) === month) {
      newMonths = [info].concat(newMonths);
    }
  });
```

them, i created my component:

```
  function Item({ value }: { value: any }) {
    let createdDay = value.item.created_at.slice(8, 10);
    let createdMonth = value.item.created_at.slice(5, 7);
    let createdYear = value.item.created_at.slice(2, 4);
    function dateSelected() {
      if (
        month === createdMonth &&
        year === createdYear &&
        (day === '00' || day == createdDay)
      ) {
        console.log('foi dateSelected');
        const [on, setOn] = useState(false);
        const Details = (on: any) => {
          if (on === true) {
            return (
              <View style={styles.infos}>
                <Text style={styles.TextInfos}>
                  {' '}
                  CPF/CNPJ: {value.item.cpf_cnpj}{' '}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.TextInfos}>
                  {' '}
                  Criado em: {value.item.created_at}{' '}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.TextInfos}>
                  {' '}
                  Endereço da carteira: {value.item.address}{' '}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.TextInfos}> Valor: {value.item.amount}BTC </Text>
              </View>
            );
          } else {
            return <View />;
          }
        };
        return (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.card}
              onPress={() => setOn(oldState => !oldState)}>
              <View style={styles.dateStyleView}>
                <Text style={styles.dateStyle}>{createdDay}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.left}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Venda rápida</Text>
                <Text style={styles.semiTitle}>
                  {
                    {
                      0: 'Pendente',
                      1: 'Aguardando conclusão',
                      2: 'Cancelado',
                      100: 'Completo',
                    }[value.item.status]
                  }
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.right2}>
                <Text style={styles.price}>R$ {value.item.requested_value}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View>{Details(on)}</View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    return dateSelected();}
```

and i call it here

```
return (
<ScrollView>
 ...
  <View style={styles.center}>
    ...
    <View style={styles.middle2}>
       ...
        <FlatList
          extraData={[refresh, newMonths]}
          data={newMonths}
          renderItem={(item: any) => <Item value={item} />}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={15}
        />


    </View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>);}
```

The scroll bar in the right, start to increase until renders all transactions from the data:
[App scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azSAW.jpg)